# Why is my RecycleView Kivy table not refreshing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, kivy, kivy-language

So whenever I try to delete an existing item from the recycleview, I have to close the application and open it again to see the deletion. I want to make it so it will automatically refresh the recycleview and show the deletion.

To navigate the application, start by going to *Record new Automation*, then type a name at the top and press *Save* in the bottom right hand corner. Then you must close the application and reopen it before pressing *Open old Automation*. Then click on the item you made and press *Delete* at the bottom. As you can see, the data is deleted, but the visual has no updated.

**kek.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore

store = JsonStore('automations.json')

class CustomScreen(Screen):
    hue = NumericProperty(0)


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    ''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''

class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        global selected
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            selected = '{0}'.format(rv.data[index])[10:-2]
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in store]


class RVScreen(Screen):
    def storedelete(self):
        try:
            store.delete(selected)
            refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data)
        except Exception:
            print("Select Something")

class NewAutoScreen(Screen):
    def recordname(self, inputname):
        if inputname:
            try:
                store.put(inputname, )
            except Exception:
                print("error")


class AutrumApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = ScreenManager()
        root.add_widget(CustomScreen(name='Autrum'))
        root.add_widget(RVScreen(name='RVScreen'))
        root.add_widget(NewAutoScreen(name='NewAutoScreen'))

        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AutrumApp().run()
```

**autrumapp.kv**

```
#:kivy 2.0
<CustomScreen>:
    hue: 4
    canvas:
        Color:
            hsv: self.hue, .5, .3
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    Label:
        font_size: 42
        text: root.name

    Button:
        text: 'Record new Automation'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1}
        size: 200, 75       
        on_release: 
            root.manager.current = "NewAutoScreen"
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            root.manager.transition.duration = .25
    Button:
        text: 'Open old Automation'
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'left': 1}
        size: 200, 75
        on_release: 
            root.manager.current = "RVScreen"
            root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
            root.manager.transition.duration = .25

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.0, 0.9, .1, .3) if self.selected else (0, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True

<RVScreen>:
    id: old
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RV:
        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            pos_hint: {'right': 1}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current = "Autrum"
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.transition.duration = .25
        
        Button:
            text: 'Open'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .05}
            size_hint: .1, .1
        Button:
            text: 'Edit'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .15}
            size_hint: .1, .1
        Button:
            text: 'Delete'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .25}
            size_hint: .1, .1
            on_press:
                old.storedelete()
                

<NewAutoScreen>:
    id: recorder
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            size_hint: .1, .1
            pos_hint: {'left': 1, 'bottom': 1}
            on_release: 
                root.manager.current = "Autrum"
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.transition.duration = .25
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            size_hint: .5, .05
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'top': 1}
            multiline: False
            text: ""
        Button:
            size_hint: .1, .1
            pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'bottom': 1}
            text: "Save"
            on_press: recorder.recordname(entry.text)
        Button:
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .4, 'bottom': 1}
            text: "Start Recording"
        Button:
            size_hint: .2, .1
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .6, 'bottom': 1}
            text: "Stop Recording"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also update the `data` attribute of the `RecycleView` to reflect the deletion. You can do that by first modifying the `kv` to provide easy access to the `RecycleView` like this:

```
<RVScreen>:
    rv: rv  # handy reference to the RV
    id: old
    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        RV:
            id: rv  # the id referenced above
```

And using the reference to the `RecycleView` in your `storedelete()` method:

```
class RVScreen(Screen):
    def storedelete(self):
        try:
            store.delete(selected)
            self.rv.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in store]  # Update RecycleView
        except Exception:
            print("Select Something")
```